# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael - Chapter -2 Toy App - Puma caught this error: uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Puma caught this error: uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)

Hi all,
I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am following Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael. I am stuck after creating `Micropost`. When I go to `localhost:3000`, the aforementioned error comes up. How should I resolve this?

Next question I have is: `aws` vs `gcp`? I am just curious about these two and which should I learn first?

Thank you very much in advance!

When I first added `users`, I can run `rails s`. However, after I add `Micropost` and run `rails s`, the following error comes up.

I have checked both `microposts_controller.rb` and `users_controller.rb` and see if I miss anything. I cannot spot anything.

```
/home/sum/code/railsbook/toy_app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<main>'
/home/sum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-
/home/sum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: does app/controllers/application_controller.rb exist?

Comment: Hi Josh, Yes, this file exits.

Comment: can you paste the contents of it?

Comment: ```Puma caught this error: uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)
/home/su/code/railsbook/toy_app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<main>'
/home/su/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/su/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/su/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
```

Comment: Thanks @JoshBrody . When I tried to add all codes, I get "too long by 4285 characters". I copy only first few lines. I checked the steps to make sure I typed the correct syntax, etc. I still couldn't find any... Thanks.

Comment: @suwin-FuriousCodeNinja Here you have write something that is wrong(doesn't follow Ruby on Rails convention can you share me controller's code or something so we can have a great look..)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the class name of users_controller.rb, Its similar to file name like `UsersController`.

otherwise maybe its rails issue: check this out https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35749